# Create dedicate folder for log files and make sure the apache logs are redirected

Tags: apache-httpd

I have a situation where I need to redirect apache logs to a specific directory from var/log/httpd/access_log in RHEL 7.

Comment: which specific directory? part of a virtual host? where should those logs then go?

Comment: Great. What's the problem with doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the file `/etc/http.conf`

```
# vi /etc/http.conf
```

Specify the path where you see `/var/log/httpd/access_log`, which is the default log directory that comes with the installation.